# Why is there no type return error in this example

Tags: typescript

```
class C {
    p:number = 3;
}
class D {
   p:number = 21321;
}

function createLabel(nameOrId: number): C {
    let a = new D();
    return a;
}

console.log(createLabel(3).p);
```

So why there is no type error because of the function returning result of type `D` instead of type `C`?

Comment: Interfaces in TypeScript are [duck typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). The TypeScript team removed this term from their documentation, but you can find it in older versions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html That means two interfaces are the same when they have the same properties. An instance of type `D` can be used everywhere an instance of `C` is expected because `D` has all properties of `C`.

Comment: This exact behavior of the TypeScript language is described in this part of the docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: @JSONDerulo Sadly they don't call it duck typing anymore. That was the main reason I was able to remember it. Therefore I prefer the outdated link.

Answer (score 0):

There's no error because typescript assumes, that those values are "any number" because you strictly typed them to `number`.

Remove strictly typing from those `p` fields and add `readonly` modificator.
With `readonly` those properties has type identical to it's value, so `C.p` has now type `3`, not just `number`.

```
class C {
    readonly p = 3;
}
class D {
   readonly p = 21321
}

const createLabel = (nameOrId: number): C => {
    let a = new D();
    return a; // Err
}

console.log(createLabel(3).p);
```

Answer (score -1):

You must define the C type and the definition of that object will be checked against the D definition if they are the same then no error if you add a class

```
Class C{p:string} // different type
```

This will return an incompatible issue.

Comment: Why do you assume the author is willing to change the type of the attribute? The whole point of the question is, why there is no error, when the attribute types are the same. Your answer doesn't really explain this behavior, and doesn't point to any resource which proofs your statements.

Comment: You have updated the code after my comment :) Anyhow hope you got your answer.